# NSXMLParserPrematureDocumentEndError = 5 // The document ended unexpectedly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I've been browsing through the questions in Stackoverflow and other forums and tried several suggested solutions but nothing works. I'm using Xcode 4.0.1 with iPhone 4.3 simulator.

The error Im receiving:

> NSXMLParserPrematureDocumentEndError = 5 // The document ended unexpectedly.

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<errorDetails>

    <errorCode>15</errorCode>
    <errorText>The very special error</errorText>

</errorDetails>
```

This is the calling code:

```
NSURL *xmlUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://172.16.202.155/results.xml"];
NSXMLParser *xmlDoc = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: xmlUrl];
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc]init];

[xmlDoc setDelegate: parser];

[xmlDoc setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[xmlDoc setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[xmlDoc setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

[xmlDoc parse];

if ([xmlDoc parserError]){
    NSLog(@"%@",[xmlDoc parserError]);
}
else NSLog(@"Parsing done!");
```

The link works, it is visible in webView.

These are implemented in XMLparser.m but it seems like they are never called for.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: i like your <errorText>The very special error </errorText>

Answer (score 4):

try changing from

```
NSURL *xmlUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://172.16.202.155/results.xml"];
```

to

```
NSURL *xmlUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.16.202.155/results.xml"];
```

Comment: If you had tested xmlURL to see if it is nil, (or inspected it in the debugger) you would have realised straight away that your URL was invalid (as a file URL).